# Alter the M values of an existing route

Tags: arcgis-desktop, linear-referencing

I have a Polyline ZM shapefile. The M values are in metres. I want to change the M values to kilometres. Seems simple enough, but I can't find a tool to do this. There is only one route in the shapefile.

Comment: perhaps a field calculation on your M-value field. Multiply the value by 1000 for kilometers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a tool to do this for a single route or a set of routes that are small enough for you to manually edit.  In an Editor session select one route and use the Edit Vertices button and then right click the route and choose "Route Measure Editing" and then choose "Apply Factor..." and enter .001 to divide all measures by 1000.  [Esri Help for Route Editing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00390000004p000000)  This does simple math.

[image: Route Apply Factor]

Here is a script that can edit many routes to do a simple math conversion of the route measures by dividing them by 1000.  This will work when you have too many routes to edit manually.  This script should only be applied to polyline routes made up of straight line segments, not polyline routes that contain true curves:

```
lyr = r"C:\Users\RFAIRHUR\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\TEST_ROUTE"  
fields = ['SHAPE@']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lyr, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        partslist = []
        partlist = []
        array = None
        feat = row[0]
        partnum = 0  

        # Count the number of points in the current multipart feature  
        partcount = feat.partCount  
        pntcount = 0  

        # Enter while loop for each part in the feature (if a singlepart feature  
        # this will occur only once)  
        #  
        while partnum < partcount:  
            part = feat.getPart(partnum)  
            pnt = part.next()  

            # Enter while loop for each vertex  
            #  
            while pnt:  
                pntcount += 1  
                if not numpy.isnan(pnt.M):
                    partlist.append(arcpy.Point(pnt.X, pnt.Y, pnt.Z, pnt.M / 1000))
                pnt = part.next()  

                # If pnt is null, either the part is finished or there is an   
                # interior ring  
                #  
                if not pnt:   
                    pnt = part.next()  
            partslist.append(arcpy.Array(partlist))
            array = arcpy.Array(partslist)
            partlist = []
            partnum += 1
        polylinefeat = arcpy.Polyline(array)
        row[0] = polylinefeat
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Check out [this post](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/102474) for an Add-In I built that does 3D or 2D measure distances on Projected route feature classes.  It handles unit conversions.  The tool is compiled for ArcGIS 10.1 and up.  The measures will reflect actual line lengths, not calibrated lengths or measures that are not somehow proportionate to the actual lengths.

However, be sure that the precision of your current measure units will not suffer due to this conversion, since the tool cannot store any significant digits in the measures that exceed the M tolerance and resolution of the original measures.  If you need a new M resolution or tolerance you would need to recreate the routes with the Create Route tool or some other tool that creates a new feature class.

If you just want simple division of the units use the calculation below to calculate a field called MMonotonicity (Long).  MMonotonicity is a measure of the simplicity of a route's measures.  It will also convert the measure units of each point of the line that has a measure by dividing by 1000 (only run this once):

Parser: Python

Use Code Block:  Checked

Pre-Logic Code Block:

```
import numpy
def MMonotonicity(feat):  
 partnum = 0  

 # Count the number of points in the current multipart feature  
 partcount = feat.partCount  
 pntcount = 0  
 mmonotonicity = 0  
 lastM = -100000000  

 # Enter while loop for each part in the feature (if a singlepart feature  
 # this will occur only once)  
 #  
 while partnum < partcount:  
  part = feat.getPart(partnum)  
  pnt = part.next()  

  # Enter while loop for each vertex  
  #  
  while pnt:  
   pntcount += 1  
   if lastM < pnt.M and lastM != -100000000:  
    mmonotonicity = mmonotonicity | 1  
   if lastM == pnt.M and lastM != -100000000:  
    mmonotonicity = mmonotonicity | 2  
   if lastM > pnt.M and lastM != -100000000:  
    mmonotonicity = mmonotonicity | 4  
   if numpy.isnan(pnt.M):  
    mmonotonicity = mmonotonicity | 8  
   lastM = pnt.M
   # converts meters to kilometers.  Only use next 2 lines once.
   if not numpy.isnan(pnt.M):
    pnt.M = pnt.M / 1000
   pnt = part.next()  

   # If pnt is null, either the part is finished or there is an   
   # interior ring  
   #  
   if not pnt:   
    pnt = part.next()  
  partnum += 1  
 return mmonotonicity
```

Expression:  MMonotonicity(!Shape!)

I am not sure this will work using the field calculator.  But this can be adapted to work in a Python script that uses a cursor instead to manipulate the shape as a variable and overwrite the shape field shape.  Python will only do this with densified curves, not true curves.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I downloaded and installed your tool and it does what it says it will do. Unfortunately I want to use the existing measures. In my shapefile the maximum measure is 711928.050, but your tool changes the maximum measure to 713.047 instead of 711.92805 which is what I want. As you said your tool uses the actual line lengths.

Comment: See my revised post for a calculation to do simple division of measures (and calculate a valuable rating of route simplicity to a field as a side benefit).  Not sure it will work.

Comment: I found a way to do what you want using Editor.  See the revised answer above.

Comment: The simple method of doing it through an edit session worked perfectly. I couldn't get the python code to work to edit the Shape field, although I could get it to calculate a value of 1 in a new field, indicating that measures are strictly increasing.

Comment: I have added a standalone Python script that will convert the measures units of all the routes in a feature class at once.  It can be used when there are too many features to edit manually.  This script should not be applied to any route polylines that contain true curve line segments within them.  True curves would be converted to straight line segments by this script, since Python does not support true curve geometry editing.